# Best way to implement UICollectionViewDataSource protocol?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates, datasource

I have theoretical question.

Currently my app is using `UICollectionView` as a way to display objects list. `UIViewController`, that contains `UICollectionView` as subview, implements `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol and acts as delegate and datasource. Datasource uses `NSFetchedResultsController` to provide data;

In my opinion this is not the best way to implement datasource, and implementing it in separate class looks way better idea. But the issue it that datasource depends on search parameters in `UITextField`, and some other buttons selections, so every time when user types text into search field  or press the any of "sorting" buttons I should update datasource (in particular fetchRequest in `NSFetchedResultsController`).

**So, finally, my question**: Is there any "best practices" of implementing datasources that depends on external parameters? Should I create separate class for datasource of leave it the way it is now? If implementing datasource as separate class - should I create datasourcedelegate for calling self-made delegate methods on delegate when datasource was updated or there is some other workarounds for this problem (I'm not considering using notifications on datasource update because as for me notifications mechanism is more global solution then I need here)?

I'm not looking for the fastest way, I just want to find out the rightest theoretical way of implementation.

Thank you all in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally implemented a concrete NSObject derived class, that implements `UICollectionViewDataSource` as well as `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` that practically translates the fetched results controller events (object inserted, updated, deleted) to collection view events (insert, update or delete cells). You can find examples on how to do this, I took mine from [here](https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController) but I implemented it as a separate class instead of a category over collection view. I found my class highly reusable, in practice I use it in all of my projects where there is a need to visualize managed objects in a collection view. A similar class can be implemented also for `UITableViewDataSource`.

If you need to update the fetch request with the search predicate, I would subclass your newly created DataSource class, and add the logic to update the fetch request right there. Say, you add a `-(void)updateSearchFilterWithText:(NSString*)text` method where you add the logic to update the fetch request of the fetched results controller. Don't forget to perform fetch again afterwards and call a `reloadData` on the collection view!

With this architecture the view controller owns this dataSource object. Every time the user updates one of your filtering text field (or other widget), the view controller calls the `updateSearchFilterWithText:` of your data source object and the rest of the work is done by this later.

Answer (score 2):

What you currently have is the standard approach. While there is no defined 'best' approach, what you describe is certainly a better approach.

Your view controller would own an instance of your new data source class, and would itself most likely handle the delegate methods (because these are actions to take rather than data to provide), so when anything changes in the UI the view controller should be 'pushing' these changes to the data source. No additional delegation should be required.

You shouldn't be creating your data source with the idea that text fields and buttons are directly driving changes in. Your data source should be presenting a generic interface where you can update the fetch request to execute (which covers the predicate and sorting) and change how the cell is configured (perhaps with a block). This way you keep your business logic in the view controller and the reusable data source code in another class that is reusable for other collection views / projects.